# IAP Receipt validation reality check needed.

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

I'm in the process of converting my paid app to a free one with IAP to remove ads. I'm using code generated by Receigen to parse the receipt. I need two crucial pieces of information from the receipt. Firstly, I'm checking the original purchase version so current users will automatically will have ads removed. I don't want upgrading paid to users to see ads right after launching the app. Secondly, for new users I'm verifying their in-app purchases. Here's my workflow that starts at application launch.

- Check and validate receipt

If receipt validates, then we're good. No problem at all really.

- If receipt doesn't exist or doesn't validate, refresh.

This is going to happen when a user upgrades to subsequent versions because the bundle ID in the receipt won't match the version specified in the validation code. I think this might also happen on fresh installs because no receipt is automatically stored locally when it's a free app? Is this correct?

I honestly don't see a refresh being a problem under normal situations. I'm not blocking the UI and it happens in the background. However the fact that it *may* trigger an App Store login prompt basically at application launch might cause a problem during the app review process. To be honest 99% of users will already be logged into the App Store when this happens. I don't know anyone that actually logs out. I can't imagine why one would. I am concerned however about Apple rejecting it because they will absolutely test for it.

What are my options then? Delay the refresh for an arbitrary period of time? What happens to my current users that will need receipt refreshment right after upgrading? How can I *not* get rejected?